# How to set up inputComboboxListOfValues search dialog case insensitive in Oracle ADF

Tags: case-sensitive, case-insensitive, oracle-adf

I use an `inputComboboxListOfValues` in an ADF page fragment (.jsff) like the following:

[image: inputComboboxListOfValues]

When I clik on "Search..." I can type what I'm looking for, but here the search is case-sensitive.

How can I set up this field case-insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dkleppinger.blogspot.com/2010/06/case-insensitive-search.html. Also, you could try setting up a case insensitive view-criteria and apply that to the LOV in the UI hints panel of the LOV setup.

Comment: I've tested this solution, but the method `getViewCriteriaClause` is not called when I use the search on the input dialog.

Comment: I've used a view criteria at the end. Check also this link: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2412163&tstart=0